# Can ecs services communicate with AWS AutoScalingGroup without NAT Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-auto-scaling

I have an architecture similar to https://github.com/aws-samples/ecs-refarch-cloudformation

I would like to know if I can have an AutoScalingGroup with instances in private subnets without using NAT Gateway?

I was experimenting with removing the NATs and adding VPC endpoints but I always end up with problem like this:

```
2022-08-21 10:55:07 UTC+1000  <MY_ECS_TEMPLATE> CREATE_FAILED The following resource(s) failed to create: [ECSAutoScalingGroup].
2022-08-21 10:55:07 UTC+1000  ECSAutoScalingGroup CREATE_FAILED Received 0 SUCCESS signal(s) out of 1. Unable to satisfy 100% MinSuccessfulInstancesPercent requirement
```

Comment: Posted the same question on ServerFault because it is more appropriate to be there.

https://serverfault.com/questions/1108706/can-ecs-services-communicate-with-aws-autoscalinggroup-without-nat-gateway

Answer (score 0):

> if I can have an AutoScalingGroup with instances in private subnets without using NAT Gateway?

Sadly no. But you can create a [vpc interface endpoints for ecs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/vpc-endpoints.html) which will enable communication with ecs from your private subnets, without the need for internet and nat.

But the error can be also from cloudformation (CFN) which can't get information back if ec2 instanses launched correctly. So you may need to add vpc endpoints for CFN as well.

Comment: I tried adding a very long list of VPC endpoints for many services including the ones you mentioned. I also examined the ecs-cluster.yaml and lifecyclehook.yaml nested templates and tried to cover all AWS services touched in these templates. Always the same error.
I hoped someone could point me to an existing template that achieves this.
At the same time it might not be possible or it might not be sensible to achieve it because if this involves too many AWS services then financially it could be better to use the NATs (even though they are rather expensive and NAT traffic is also expensive)

Comment: @user2134216 There can be many other issues why your interface endpoints don't work. E.g. wrong security groups. Wrong VPC setup, subnets, route tables. Sadly your question lacks any relevant details about any of these. Thus its difficult to speculate.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. We use AWS Batch, which is based on AutoScaling Groups. We use squid proxy for internet access from private subnets. After I created few endpoints as mentioned before, spot VM started. Next I had to update AMI for these VM and set proper proxy/noproxy. And it works.